# Laravel 5.7 Relationship One To Many Columns

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database, laravel-migrations

i have team and match table. All match information save on match table with two team, winner team, match time etc.

on match table i have three field team_1, team_2, winner_team
i want to relation those field with team table

**Here is my code**

**Team Model**

```
class Team extends Model
{
    public function league()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\League');
    }



      public function matchs()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Match');
        }

    }
```

**Match Model**

```
class Match extends Model
{
    public function team_1()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team','id');
    }

    public function team_2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team','team_2');
    }

    public function winner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Team','winner');
    }

    public function league()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\League');
    }

    public function teams() {
        return $this->team_1()->merge($this->team_2());
    }
}
```

**Migration File**

```
Schema::create('matches', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('team_1')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('team_2')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('league_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('winner')->nullable();
            $table->dateTime('match_time');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('team_1')->references('id')->on('teams')
                ->onDelete('restrict')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('team_2')->references('id')->on('teams')
                ->onDelete('restrict')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('league_id')->references('id')->on('leagues')
                ->onDelete('restrict')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('winner')->references('id')->on('teams')
                ->onDelete('restrict')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function team_1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_1');
}

public function team_2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'team_2');
}
```

Comment: which model contains those relation?

Comment: On Match model contains this relation